# Can anyone tell me how can I get read receipts of messages on Slack?

Tags: bots, iot, slack

I am developing a bot for Slack.
Can anyone help me with the message read receipts?

Comment: I don't think Slack has this feature.

Comment: I read it on a Blog that Slack supports the feature, but could not find some source for it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the self promotion but Slack has yet to add this feature. We saw this need as well for our team, so we decided to go ahead and create a slack app that has this feature.

**How it works**

Whenever you open a channel and read the messages, an :eye: reaction will be added to the latest message you've read inside that channel. This allows you to see who has read up to what point.

If you're interested in the app, the product is called [SlackReadIt](http://slackreadit.com)

Comment: does each team-member need to authorize slack-read-it ? @Cosmic9Studios

Comment: Yes. It's linked to your user account since we add and remove reactions on your behalf.

Comment: @Cosmic9Studios I think it is no longer working, is it?